# What data type should I use for large and accurate numbers?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple Android calculator app which calculates percentages based on the numbers the users input. Usually it's within a reasonable value, so I used int. But I ran into problems with big numbers, and int automatically disposes of decimal values, so I'm trying to find an alternative. What data type should I use for big numbers, that is very accurate?

Comment: java.math.BigDecimal.

Comment: The [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class, maybe?

Comment: Thanks guys! Andy Turner and Mike M.

Comment: You cannot use operators with `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger`. Instead, you have to use methods such as `add`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What data type should I use for large and accurate numbers?

I would use a [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) per the Javadoc it is

> Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers. A BigDecimal consists of an arbitrary precision integer *unscaled value* and a 32-bit integer *scale*.

For example,

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("1000");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.001");
BigDecimal c = a.multiply(b);
System.out.println(c.toPlainString());
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! But what is the *range* of BigDecimal?

Comment: @ideaman Limited only by the memory available to Java (so obscenely large)